# git client side hooks for comparing commit message and modified files

Tags: git, githooks

I already have a server side hook that has logic around files being checked in and can reject the commit.

What I would like to do is create a client side hook so that developers get an early warning of the problem before they commit to their local repository to avoid the complications around fixing up those commits.

The problem I am having is that our logic involves both the list of changed files and the commit message (e.g., some files are locked and can't be checked in unless the name of the file is in the commit message, indicating that the developer is aware of the issue and is overriding it.)

It looks like the message is available in the commit-msg hook and the list of files is available in the pre-commit hook. Is there a way I can get both of these at the same time or communicate between the two hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of files with their status by running

```
files=$(git status -s)
```

within the `commit-msg` hook.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. I have also learned that this works well:

"git diff --staged --name-only"